# Lexical or Preprocessor issue: 'realm/keys.hpp' file not found

Tags: ios, realm, cocoapods, xcode11.4

I recently switched to Xcode 11.4 and using Swift 5. I run pod install, Realm and RealmSwift installed with the latest version till date. Now when I run the project, its showing me an error:

**..../Pods/Realm/include/binding_context.hpp:24:10: 'realm/keys.hpp' file not found**

[image]

**Podfile:**

```
pod 'Realm', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true
pod 'RealmSwift', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true
```

Realm framework version: 4.4.1

Cocoapod version: 1.9.1

Xcode version: 11.4

Why is the error occurring and how can we get rid of the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve the issue, I had to:

1. remove `pod 'RealmSwift'` from my podfile
2. run `pod install`
3. re-add `pod 'RealmSwift'` in my podfile
4. run `pod install` again to get latest version. It resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the error by updating my pods. I ran `pod update` in the terminal after navigating to the project folder.